# Кастинг в коде это нормально?

Tags: c++

Кастинг в коде это нормальное явление или повод задуматься над тем что, что то с кодом не так?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Кастинг, кастингу рознь. К примеру, если у вас в коде есть `static_cast`, то это может быть подозрительно, но вряд-ли опасно. Тем не менее, даже со `static_cast` нужно убедиться, что это не просто безответственная попытка «заткнуть» компилятор, а явное и нужное преобразование. Как правило, такие вещи нужны на стыке кода библиотек, но, в идеальном случае лучше избегать и `static_cast`

Если у вас в коде появляется `dynamic_cast`, то есть вероятность, что вы неправильно используете полиморфизм. Тем не менее, с точки зрения корректности программы, `dynamic_cast` не является проблемой. Он не может ничего такого добавить, чтобы сделало программу некорректной(т.е. он не служит «затычкой» компилятора). Поэтому наличие `dynamic_cast` может служить признаком неправильного дизайна(и пессимизации), но не более того.

Если у вас в коде есть `const_cast`, то наиболее вероятно, что у вас в коде имеет место ошибка дизайна, которая должна быть исправлена как можно скорее. В противном случае вы сами знаете, что делаете и `const_cast` там не случаен. Прибегать к нему стоит лишь в том случае, когда других вариантов уже не осталось. И даже в этом случае стоит 100 раз всё обдумать и взвесить, т.к. `const_cast` не снимает константность с объектов, которые были рождены таковыми изначально. Точнее он может снять, а может и не снять — UB, если не ошибаюсь будет в этом случае.

Наконец, если у вас в коде есть `reinterpret_cast` и он не находится в коде, который работает на стыке кроссплатформенного модуля и модуля специфичного конкретной ОС, то у вас с большой долей вероятности есть проблема.

Если же у вас в коде есть C-style касты, то, сначала, замените их на C++ аналоги, а потом удалите те, что не являются необходимостью.

В целом, любой оператор явного преобразования является потенциальной проблемой, поэтому их использование желательно свести к минимуму. Каждое такое использование должно иметь смысл и быть необходимым.

Comment: Со всем согласен, за исключением `static_cast'ов`. Они тоже разные бывают. В том числе и **небезопасные**, как например кастинг к базовому классу/потомку, экземпляра которого не существует фактически. В лучшем случае - это чтение/запись за пределами выделенного блока памяти.

Comment: @mega, может и быть опасным, но, он наименее опасный из всех(не считая `dynamic`). Вообще этим я хотел подчеркнуть тот факт, что наличие `static_cast` в коде может не говорить об ошибке, тогда как наличие 3-х других это, зачастую, именно ошибка.

Comment: Он опасен в той же степени, как и все остальные касты. Точно так же, `reinterpret_cast` может не означать ошибку. Нет тут каких-то привилегий: такие - сильно опасные, а другие - не очень. Все они блокируют обычную логику компилятора, что может приводить к проблемам в поддержке кода.

Comment: @mega, ну я с Вами не согласен. `static_cast` не позволяет конвертировать между собой сущности, которые не могут быть сконвертированы(не имеет между собой общих свойств) , поэтому, как правило, представляет собой куда меньшую опасность

Comment: "static_cast не позволяет конвертировать между собой сущности, которые не могут быть сконвертированы(не имеет между собой общих свойств)" -- позволяет, выше я уже [приводил пример](https://ideone.com/SLtfF6).

Comment: @mega, это обычный downcast. B и A состоят в отношениях наследования. Так что — нет, не позволяет.

Comment: Это обычный `static_cast`, и опять же - да, позволяет: смотрите внимательно на ошибку и смотрите на преобразование. -1 за отрицание очевидного.

Comment: @mega, я не понимаю, о чём тут спорить . Я с Вами не согласен и  уже объяснил почему. Пишите свой ответ, если мой считаете не верным.

Comment: Я уже сказал, в чем ответ неверный и привел аргументы. Ваших не увидел.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33731/discussion-between-ixsci-and-mega).