# Как можно убрать предупреждение discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type

Tags: c, glfw

Есть функция, которая возвращает высоту окна:

```
unsigned mr_GLFWGetWindowHeight(const GLFWwindow* _window)
{
    int height;
    glfwGetWindowSize(_window, NULL, &height);
    return (unsigned) height;
}
```

Проблема в том, что функция `glfwGetWindowSize` объявлена так:

```
void glfwGetWindowSize(GLFWwindow * window, // <-- нет const
                       int *        width,
                       int *        height 
                       )
```

Как можно избавиться от предупреждения, кроме как убрать `const`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Явно прикастить, то есть заменить

```
glfwGetWindowSize(_window, NULL, &height);
```

на

```
glfwGetWindowSize((GLFWwindow *) _window, NULL, &height);
```

Хотя, кажется, [так плохо делать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479210/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE/479213#479213) (абзац про `const_cast`).

Если библиотечная функция действительно не изменяет `_window`, то идеально было бы [изменить их код](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/src/window.c#L496) и отправить им pull request.

Comment: Спасибо, предупреждение убралось. Только объясните, почему так делать - плохо.

Comment: Небольшое объяснение есть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479213/227016) (абзац про `const_cast`). Мне кажется здесь действительно имеет место ошибка дизайна на уровне библиотеки, судя по их коду можно изменить функцию `glfwGetWindowSize` чтобы она принимала `const GLFWwindow* _window`.